# Logic of assigning a group based on different criteria with dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data consists of `ID`s who take supplements (`A`, `AB`, `B`, `C`) on specified dates as follows:

| ID | A | AB | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-04-01 |
| 2 | *null* | 2021-06-01 | *null* | 2021-08-01 |
| 3 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-08-01 | *null* |
| 4 | *null* | *null* | 2021-11-01 | *null* |
| 5 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-06-01 | *null* | *null* |
| 6 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-02 |
| 7 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-02 |
| 8 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-09-01 | 2021-11-02 |
| 9 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-09-01 | 2021-08-02 |
| 10 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-09-01 | 2021-07-02 |
| 11 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | *null* |
| 12 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | *null* |
| 13 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-10-01 |
| 14 | 2021-08-01 | *null* | *null* | 2021-09-01 |
| 15 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-12-01 | *null* | 2021-09-01 |
| 16 | 2021-10-01 | *null* | *null* | 2021-09-01 |

**Supplement `AB` consists of supplements `A` and `B`.**

I need to classify each `ID` and receive the date of an ID taking `B` or `AB` or both together if the following criteria apply:

1. `B` or `AB` must be taken before `C` (or `C` `IS NULL`).
2. If `B` is taken, `A` or `AB` needs to be taken before `B` or simultaneously. If `AB` was taken before `B`, `AB` is the date to receive. When `A` was taken before `B`, `B` is the date to receive.

Furthermore, sometimes an ID can receive supplements together, which is also okay. For example `ID` 11 with `A` and `AB`.

When I take a look at the table, it's easy to apply but putting this into a logic does not work as I expected.

This is my attempt which unfortunately gives wrong results:
Maybe there is a completely different method to do something like this?

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN (AB IS NOT NULL AND (AB <= B OR B IS NULL)) THEN AB
        WHEN (A IS NOT NULL AND (A <= B OR B IS NULL)) THEN B
        ELSE NULL
    END AS SupplementDate
FROM Table1
WHERE (B IS NOT NULL OR AB IS NOT NULL) 
AND (C IS NULL OR (B IS NOT NULL AND (A IS NOT NULL OR AB IS NOT NULL)))
ORDER BY ID;
```

Data and approach: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ClHcFRJC)

The expected result:

| ID | A | AB | B | C | SupplementDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-02-01 |
| 2 | *null* | 2021-06-01 | *null* | 2021-08-01 | 2021-06-01 |
| 3 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-08-01 | *null* | *null* |
| 4 | *null* | *null* | 2021-11-01 | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-06-01 | *null* | *null* | 2021-06-01 |
| 6 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-02 | 2021-11-01 |
| 7 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-02 | 2021-09-01 |
| 8 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-09-01 | 2021-11-02 | 2021-09-01 |
| 9 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-09-01 | 2021-08-02 | *null* |
| 10 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-09-01 | 2021-07-02 | *null* |
| 11 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | *null* | 2021-09-01 |
| 12 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | *null* | 2021-09-01 |
| 13 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-09-01 | *null* | 2021-10-01 | 2021-09-01 |
| 14 | 2021-08-01 | *null* | *null* | 2021-09-01 | *null* |
| 15 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-12-01 | *null* | 2021-09-01 | *null* |
| 16 | 2021-10-01 | *null* | *null* | 2021-09-01 | *null* |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions aren't 100% clear, but it looks like you can do it like this

```sql
SELECT *,
    CASE
      WHEN (LEAST(AB, B) <= C OR C IS NULL)
       AND (LEAST(AB, A) <= B OR B IS NULL)
      THEN LEAST(AB, B)
    END AS SupplementDate
FROM table1
ORDER BY ID;
```

In older versions of SQL Server, you can't use `LEAST`. So you need to do a bunch of `CASE` or `IIF`

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
      WHEN (IIF(AB IS NOT NULL, IIF(B IS NOT NULL AND B < AB, B, AB), B) <= C OR C IS NULL)
       AND (IIF(AB IS NOT NULL, IIF(A IS NOT NULL AND A < AB, A, AB), A) <= B OR B IS NULL)
      THEN IIF(AB IS NOT NULL, IIF(B IS NOT NULL AND B < AB, B, AB), B)
    END AS SupplementDate
FROM table1
ORDER BY ID;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/NxBcK8KM)

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. `LEAST` does not work. I was not aware of `IIF`. I added another `ID` which needs to have the `SupplementDate` on 2021-03-12, because first `A`, then `B`, `AB`, `C`. Do you know how to get this included? https://dbfiddle.uk/xJaj6k66

Comment: What if the order is A, AB, B or AB, A, B then what do you want?

Comment: For A, AB, B  - AB is the date and for AB, A, B - AB is the date. The problem is that A must appear first or at the latest at the same time, regardless of whether it is included in AB or as standalone A.